# Showing that $||x|| = \max\{|\alpha_{\lambda} \mid y \in E|\}$ is a norm on $X$.

Tags: real-analysis

Let $X$ be a linear space on $\mathbb{K}$. Let $\{x_{\lambda}\}_{\lambda \in \Lambda}$ be a Hamel basis of $X$ where $\Lambda$ is an index set. That is, for every $x \in X$, there exists a unique representation $$x = \sum_{\lambda \in E}\alpha_{\lambda}x_{\lambda}$$ where $\alpha_{\lambda} \in \mathbb{K}$ and $E \subset \Lambda$ a finite set. Show that the function $||\cdot ||: X \to \mathbb{R}$ defined by $$||x|| = \max\{|\alpha_{\lambda} | \mid \lambda \in E\}$$ is a norm on $X$.

---

Edit:

For this problem we know that a Hamel basis is when $span(A) = X$ and to be a norm, if we have $p: X \to R$ then $p$ needs to homogeneous, non-negative, have the triangle inequality property, and have that $p(x) = 0 \iff x=0$.

Comment: Check the properties of a norm:

triangle inequality, non-degeneracy etc.

Comment: Make a list of the properties you need to check. Start at the top. Say where you have difficulties.

Comment: @DanielFischer Well, i'm not really sure how to work with our function. Say we start by showing that it is homogeneous. i.e., $p(\alpha x) = |\alpha|p(x)$.  I'm not sure how to work with the function.

Comment: Homogeneity is okay to start with. So, you have $x$ and $t\cdot x$. What are the coefficients of $t\cdot x$ with respect to the basis?

Comment: @DanielFischer I'm not sure what you mean. Well, $t \cdot x = t \cdot \sum_{y \in E}\alpha_{\lambda }x_{\lambda}$.

Comment: Well, so if $t\cdot x = \sum \beta_\lambda x_\lambda$, what are the $\beta_\lambda$?

Comment: How is $t \cdot x = \sum \beta_{\lambda} x_{\lambda}$? I don't think we defined $\beta_{\lambda}$ anywhere.

Comment: We define the $\beta_\lambda$ in that way. The $\beta_\lambda$ are the coefficients of $t\cdot x$ with respect to the basis $\{x_\lambda : \lambda \in \Lambda\}$.

Comment: I don't think I'm going to understand this problem unless someone posts a solution for it. That way i'll be able to piece information together.

Comment: What is this $y$ doing in the definition of the norm?